# Regex Match All Except Leading and Trailing Spaces Around Commas (including comma)

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to match **everything** except commas and any spaces around them. However, I would like it to match spaces between words. This is what I have so far:

```
/[^,\s][a-zA-Z0-9_ !@#$%^&*()]+/gi
```

It's matching everything except commas and trailing spaces, but it's including the leading spaces. Here's the link to test it [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oQ3Bjj/2).

I'm trying to wrap span tags around key terms. This is what I would want the end result to be:

```
<span>Some text</span>   ,    <span>Some more     text</span>
```

I'm currently using

```
.replace(/([^,\s][a-zA-Z0-9_ !@#$%^&*()]+)/gi, "<span>$1</span>")
```

and it updates the span tags in a contenteditable div. I'm using it to place bubbles using CSS around key terms, and are updated after every input. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I'm currently using `.replace(/([^,\s][a-zA-Z0-9_ !@#$%^&*()]+)/gi, "<span>$1</span>")` and it updates the span tags in a contenteditable div after every input. How would I incorporate `split()` instead?

Comment: @JamesMarquez You should add your comment in your question, that would help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex would be:

```
([\s\S]+?)(\s*,\s*|$)
```

then within `replace()` method back-reference to both capturing groups:

```js
const regex = /([\s\S]+?)(\s*,\s*|$)/g;

const str = `uncased is a test   ,  vertical this is a tests
80000   ,     bertical
80000     ,       vertical
#303 cardio  endo,  kljafklj\$!asdfkj`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, '<span>$1</span>$2');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Before your edit, it updated the span tags only after a comma was entered. After your edit, it works exactly as intended. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. You may also consider to up-vote the answer if it helped you find a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: I did another test (the `([\s\S]+?)` was bothering me), try with a string that starts with leading spaces, you will end with `<span> *multiple spaces* uncased is a test</span>`, otherwise that works pretty well.

Comment: No difficulties. You just need to consider it in matching by prepending `\s*` to regex @romain-aga

Comment: Maybe you could complete your answer with it, then ;)

Comment: Here's a playground site I made to test it out in [playground test site with answer](http://jamesmarquezportfolio.com/business_intelligence_web_app/playground.html) and this is the web search app it'll be incorporated into [search web app](http://jamesmarquezportfolio.com/business_intelligence_web_app/bi_search.html).

Comment: Comments are enough for it. @romain-aga

Comment: I noticed that if two commas are in a row, the second comma will match.

Comment: You can use `+` quantifier: `,+` @JamesMarquez

Answer (score -1):

Does this do the trick ?

```
/((?:(\w|[-!@#$%^&*()])+( (\w|[-!@#$%^&*()]))*)+)/g
```

Or

```
/((?:(\w|[-!@#$%^&*()])+( {1,MAX_NUMBER_OF_SPACES}(\w|[-!@#$%^&*()]))*)+)/g
```